# Change "Add This" email link to go to contact page

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis, add-this-event

I am using the [Add This](http://www.addthis.com/) plugin on my site and would like to customise the email button to go to my own contact page. Add This doesn't seem to give that functionality, so I'm trying to do it with JS.

I can't seem to stop the default Add This popup from firing. Does anyone know how I could do it?

**preventDefault**, **stopImmediatePropagation**, and **stopPropagation** don't seem to stop it. Maybe because they are JQuery and the Add This event is native JS?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$('body').on('click', '.at-svc-email', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('test');
});
```

The alert comes up, followed by the Add This popup.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your question. (1) You will confuse your users. The email link is for them to email the page to others, not for them to contact you. (2) `preventDefault`, `stopImmediatePropagation`, and `stopPropagation` *are* native JavaScript, not jQuery. That said, I'm not sure how to answer your question; I thought I had it figured out, but my answer didn't work, so I deleted it. I will repost it if I figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your points Ed. I meant "email popup", not contact page, I have amended the text to correct this. I did not know those methods were native JS, so thanks for letting me know!